# Calculating time difference between two rows with condition of matching code of start and end

Tags: mysql

I have data as below:

```
uid ,access_code , access_date
(1,'200', '2017-08-06 06:59:04'),
(1,'204', '2017-08-06 21:11:21'),
(1,'200', '2017-09-30 21:33:45'),
(1,'510', '2017-09-30 22:11:40'),
(1,'200', '2017-10-28 07:09:44'),
(1,'200', '2017-10-28 07:12:21'),
(1,'510', '2017-10-28 07:12:51'),
(1,'510', '2017-10-28 07:13:20')
```

I would like to get the records in pair ie 1 row of access_code=200 with next access_code=510 or 204 and calculate the time difference.Expected result as below:

```
(1,'2017-08-06 06:59:04','2017-08-06 21:11:21',14:12:17)
(1,'2017-09-30 21:33:45','2017-09-30 22:11:40',00:37:55)
(1,'2017-10-28 07:09:44','2017-10-28 07:12:51',00:03:07)
(1,'2017-10-28 07:12:21','2017-10-28 07:13:20',00:00:59)
```

I have below sql query but the the query only able to handle if every access_code=200 is follow by 204 or 510. For cases if there is two 200 then follow by two 510 or 204 then it will not works.

```
select uid,start,stop, TIMEDIFF(stop, start) AS duration FROM (
select uid,access_date,access_code,@start AS start,
        @start := IF(access_code = '200', access_date, NULL) AS prev_start,
        @stop  := IF(access_code = '510' or access_code = '204' ,  access_date, NULL) AS stop,
        @uid  := uid AS guid from Table1  order by uid,access_date) as tmp,
        (SELECT @start:=NULL, @stop:=NULL, @uid:=NULL) AS vars
WHERE  start IS not  NULL AND stop  is not NULL order by duration desc;
```

SQL demo is here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f272ec/1

Thank you.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you need. You need to select each row's uid, access code, start, stop, and time difference where the subsequent row with the same uid is a 204 or 510 but not where the subsequent occurrence of the same uid is a different code?

Comment: @AltimusPrime, every 200 must come in with a 204/510, so i need to select and calculate the time difference. the issue is that 200 is not always have 204/510 right after. Could be two 200 then come with two 204/510. Then i need to pair first 200 with first 204/510, then second 200 with second 204/510.

Comment: What if there's a 200 that doesn't match on a 204 or 510? Ignore those instances?

Comment: Also, are you adverse to using a stored procedure that involves creating temporary tables?

Comment: @AltimusPrime, i run a command to make sure the count of 200 is tally with 204/510. So, 200 is always in pair with 204/510. Temporary table is ok if it works.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to get the records in pair ie 1 row of access_code=200
> with next access_code=510 or 204 and calculate the time
> difference.Expected result as below:

If I understand correctly, you want to select the time difference between rows of a given uid where the access_code is 200 but where the next instance of the `uid` has either a `204` or `510` access_code and then get the timedifference between them.

This isn't pretty, but if I understand what you want, then this sloppy query will handle that and exclude cases where the subsequent request was also a 200 access_code.

```
select 
    a.uid,
    a.access_date as `startDate`,
    (select access_code from Table1 b where b.uid=a.uid and b.access_date > a.access_date order by access_date asc limit 1) as following_code,
    (select b.access_date from Table1 b where b.uid=a.uid and b.access_date > a.access_date order by access_date asc limit 1) as `stopDate`,
    timediff(
        (select b.access_date from Table1 b where b.uid=a.uid and b.access_date > a.access_date order by access_date asc limit 1),
        a.access_date
    ) as duration
from Table1 a
where 
    (select access_code from Table1 b where b.uid=a.uid and b.access_date > a.access_date order by access_date asc limit 1)
    and a.access_code = 200
    having following_code = 204
    or following_code = 510
```

result:

```
"uid"   "startDate" "following_code"    "stopDate"  "duration"
"1" "2017-08-06 06:59:04"   "204"   "2017-08-06 21:11:21"   "14:12:17"
"1" "2017-09-30 21:33:45"   "510"   "2017-09-30 22:11:40"   "00:37:55"
"1" "2017-10-28 07:12:21"   "510"   "2017-10-28 07:12:51"   "00:00:30"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However my expected result is 
(1,'2017-08-06 06:59:04','2017-08-06 21:11:21',14:12:17)
(1,'2017-09-30 21:33:45','2017-09-30 22:11:40',00:37:55)
(1,'2017-10-28 07:09:44','2017-10-28 07:12:51',00:03:07)
(1,'2017-10-28 07:12:21','2017-10-28 07:13:20',00:00:59)